# php - Laravel Auth and Session not working on Live Server

Tags: php, laravel

**SESSION**

**controller:**
 Session::flash('flash_notice', 'Registered ,Please check your Email');

**In View**
@if (Session::has('message'))

{{ Session::get('message') }}

@endif

in my view Session data not dispalying on Live Server

**Auth**

Auth::check() and Auth::user() gives me false and null on Liver Server

But on localhost It is working fine.

Plz help me out here

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it your sessions are not being set properly and are being regenerated with each request. (Check your session storage on the live server)

Ensure your session config file is correct, specifically the domain, path and secure options.

Comment: what is session domain

Comment: i am storing in storage/sessions

Comment: The session domain should be the url the site is running on (e.g: domain.com) depending on if you're using subdomains etc theres a few different options there, a little more info could be good. Also are any sessions being saved into your storage?